# display a document content like pdf from response stream to a wpf app

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, stream, cefsharp

In my WPF app i use CefSharp so users can make browse internet. I want to catch the case that user is requesting a content type like pdf and show it's content in a new view without save or print tools ect. 
With this code i'm saving the file as pdf locally.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fileUrl);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        try
        {


            var theStream = new object();
            string fileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Printings" + @"\test.pdf";

              using (var stream = File.Create(fileName))
              {
                  File.SetAttributes(fileName, FileAttributes.Normal);
                  response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(stream);
              }
```

Then i open a new window with a browser and i load the pdf as embed in html like this: code in new window

```
string absolute = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Printings" + @"\test.pdf"; 


browser.NavigateToString(@"<HTML><embed width="+width+" height="+height+" src=" + absolute+"></HTML>");
```

The pdf is sucessfully loaded but the problem is that save and print tools are remaining.
Any ideas for alternatives;

Comment: Search to see if what your asking is possible with `Chrome`, not sure that it is.

Comment: With cefsharp(it uses the chronium engine is not possible). so i try to find a solution with streams and xaml controls

Comment: For reference `CefSharp` is based on the `Chromium Content API`. You may need to resort to having an external `PDF viewer` or editing the `pak` files that contain the `styling` for the `PDF Viewer`.